# Prolog ERROR: Out of global stack

Tags: prolog

When i'm trying to run this code  returns an error "**Out of global stack**".
Can anyone help me solve this?

```
start:- findDiseases([headache,weakness,heartbeat,loose_concentration], Diseases),write(Diseases).

findDiseases(PositiveSymptoms, Diseases) :- findDiseases(PositiveSymptoms, Diseases, []).
findDiseases([], Answer, Answer).
findDiseases([H|T], Diseases, Answer) :-
    findall(Disease, (kb(Disease,Simptoms_list,Feauture_list),member(H,Simptoms_list);member(H,Feauture_list)), As),
    append(As, Answer, NewAnswer),
    findDiseases(T, Diseases, NewAnswer).

% kb(diagnosis,symptoms_list,features_list).    
kb(iron_def,[headache,dizziness,cold,weakness,fatigue,heartbeat,loose_concentration,swelling_tongue,breath],[gender,pregnancy,vitamin_poor_diet,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,rtc]).
kb(thalass,[loose_appetite,painful_spleen,pale_skin],[gender,parent1,parent2,face_features,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,hbf,hba1,hba2,rtc]).
kb(minor_thalass,[headache,fatigue,weakness,pale_skin,swelling_tongue,cold,heartbeat,loose_concentration,breath,dizziness],[vitamin_poor_diet,gender,pregnancy,parent1,parent2,hbaf,hba2,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,rtc]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
findall(Disease, (
   kb(Disease,Simptoms_list,Feauture_list),(
     member(H,Simptoms_list);member(H,Feauture_list)
   )), As),
...
```

Note the added parenthesis aroud the disjunction. Of course, it helps readability to proper indent the code.

Comment: I read it about 5 times...okkk...thanks a lot...
But now it shows 
`?- start.
[_G1357]
true .`

Comment: I tested it, after the correction, I get `?- start.
[iron_def,minor_thalass,iron_def,minor_thalass,iron_def,minor_thalass,iron_def,minor_thalass]
true.
`. I think you introduced some typo...